# MySQL query cerain hours

Tags: mysql, search

New to MySql and am trying to query a table to get just certain hours and minutes such as

05:00:00.   Have been using following, but only getting the 05:00:00 hours but need both 05 and 11 hours...

```
SELECT *  FROM `UMHMwind` 
WHERE Hour(`dt`) = "05,11" AND MINUTE(`dt`) = "0".
```

Probably a simple solution but have been unable to find anything helpful online.

Answer (score 2):

To specify a list of values, you use the [`IN` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT *  FROM `UMHMwind` 
WHERE HOUR(`dt`) IN (5, 11) AND MINUTE(`dt`) = 0
```

Note that when using functions around dates, indexes will not be used.

The documentation is your friend.

Comment: I think you mean  IN ('5', '11')

Comment: @Musa I do not, they are not string values.

Comment: so why have you put them in single quoates?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT *
FROM UMHMwind
WHERE Hour(dt) IN (5, 11) AND MINUTE(dt) = 0
```

Note that the `hour()` and `minute()` function return integers, so you should compare the results to integers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check a value is equal to either **a value** OR **another** (I mean hours in this case): you can use:

- **=** operator

`... where HOUR(dt) = 5 or HOUR(dt) = 11 ...`

- **IN** operator

`... where HOUR(dt) in (5, 11) ...`

The second is a short-hand, so I suggest it.